# Extract Only Values as csv format in gremlin

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to extract values from Graph database. i am trying with the below gremlin console command but it is returning key value pairs, we can convert this to list.

```
%%gremlin

g.V().hasLabel('airport').limit(2).project('id','label','region','country').by(id()).by(label()).by('region').by('country').fold()
```

output

```
[{'id': '1', 'label': 'airport', 'region': 'US-GA', 'country': 'US'}, {'id': '2', 'label': 'airport', 'region': 'US-AK', 'country': 'US'}]
```

Expected output:

```
'1', 'airport', 'US-GA', 'US'
'2', 'airport', 'US-AK', 'US'

or

[['1','airport','US-GA','US'], ['2','airport', 'US-AK','US']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `project` you can use `values`. Steps like `project` and `valueMap` return a key:value map, whereas `values` does not include the keys in its result.

```
gremlin> g.V().
           hasLabel('airport').
           limit(2).
           local(union(id(),label(),values('region','country')).fold())

==>[1,airport,US,US-GA]
==>[2,airport,US,US-AK]
```

As an alternative you can just add a `select(values)` to your current query which I think I prefer as it avoids needing the `local` and `union` steps.

```
gremlin> g.V().
           hasLabel('airport').
           limit(2).
           project('id','label','region','country').
             by(id()).
             by(label()).
             by('region').by('country').
           select(values).
           fold()

==>[[1,airport,US-GA,US],[2,airport,US-AK,US]]
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, I think i tried with values step. But order was not of what i mentioned in values step. As you see in above result region and country are swapped. Also, to make it easy to write into to other databases i want to have this as one list and each row should be inner list so that i can write into pandas dataframe.

Comment: I added a second example that takes your original query and just extracts the values from the map. The order in which results are returned is not guaranteed. If you need a specific order it's best to add an `order` step to your query.

Comment: It was working fine in gremlin console. Is this different in Glue excution, i got Failed message Type Error: id() takes exactly one arguement (given 0 arguments).

Comment: If you are using Python to avoid name collisions you have to use `id_()`

Comment: No Luck, when i do this it says id_ not defined. My code is "g.V().hasLabel('airport').limit(2).project('id','label','region','country').by(id_()).by(label()).by('region').by('country').select(values).fold()"

Comment: OK - maybe id() is not one that has a shorthand form - try doing `T.id` instead. I tested that and it works fine. >>> g.V('3').project('id').by(T.id).next()
{'id': '3'} Alternatively you can do `__.id()`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you kelvin, I tried as here vertices = g.V().hasLabel('airport').limit(2).project('id','label','region','country').by(T.id).by(label()).by('region').by('country').select(values).fold(). but still throwing error "name T is not defined". Glue Console itself show different color.

Comment: Using Python you need to import the T class from Gremlin Python. Do you perhaps want to open a new question and we can discuss it there? In my code I often do `from gremlin_python.process.traversal import *` as the T enum and many other useful things are defined in that file (traversal.py)